# Windows Phone - Pivot and parent Page

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, user-controls, pivot, windows-phone

I have a PivotControl inside a PPhoneAppplicationPage. Ideally I'd like to show the appbar items from the page at all times, and merge them with items defined in the UserControl which shows in each PivotItem. I've tried a few different things, but only the outer (the PhoneApplicationPage) appbar seems to show.

Answer (score 1):

The AppBar items are owned by the Page, not the PivotItems. But you can add/remove then dynamically as needed:

Your Page has an ApplicationBar property which has a Buttons and a MenuItems property. Add and remove buttons/menuitems there programmatically as needed whenever a new PivotItem gets selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different appbars for each pivot item in a pivot. try the code below

```
<phone:Pivot>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger>
            <appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger.SelectionMappings>
                <appBarUtils:SelectionMapping SourceIndex="0" TargetIndex="0"/>
            </appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger.SelectionMappings>

            <appBarUtils:SwitchAppBarAction>
                <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="0"   BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.home.png" Text="home" Command="{Binding HomeNavigationCommand}"/>
                </appBarUtils:AppBar>

                <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="1" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.home.png" Text="home" Command="{Binding HomeNavigationCommand}"/>
                </appBarUtils:AppBar>

                <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="2" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.home.png" Text="home" Command="{Binding HomeNavigationCommand}"/>
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.money.png" Text="collection" Command="{Binding CollectionPageCommand}"/>
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.check.rest.png" Text="ok" Command="{Binding OrderConfirmationButtonCommand}"/>
                </appBarUtils:AppBar>

                <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="3"  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton x:Name="ConfirmationAppBarButton" IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.cancel.rest.png" Text="cancel" Command="{Binding OrderCancelButtonCommand}"/>
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.check.rest.png" Text="ok" Command="{Binding OrderConfirmationButtonCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding Model.EnableCheck,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </appBarUtils:AppBar>

            </appBarUtils:SwitchAppBarAction>
        </appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</phone:Pivot>
```